# spring web flow tranisiton on-to

Tags: java, spring-webflow

following is my flow,

```
<view-state id="fileUpload" view="FileUpload" redirect="false" popup="false" model="scanDataHolder">

        <on-render>
            <evaluate expression="fileUpload.setupNewFileUploadHolder(holder, flowRequestContext,externalContext)" />
        </on-render>    

        <transition on="process" to="uploadreport" validate="false">
            <evaluate expression="fileUpload.process(holder, flowRequestContext,externalContext)" />                
        </transition>       

        <transition on="doneWithFileUpload" to="doneWithFileUpload" validate="false"/>                          
    </view-state>   

    <view-state id="uploadreport" view="renderReport"   redirect="false" popup="true" model="retailScan"/>
```

above flow works well and good. but, when my flow comes here

```
<transition on="process" to="uploadreport"
```

I need to go to `<view-state id="uploadreport" view="renderReport"..../>` and also to `<view-state id="fileUpload" view="FileUpload".../>`

one will open an excel report and other will clean the field used to browse the file and shows with brief results of the file...

any help is appreciated!

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're asking, but you can't from the server send back two responses to a single request. That is, you can't send the flow to two view-states at the same time. You'd need to send back a single view that included some client-side code to send a second request for the second view.

Comment: you got it right. it works for me and I can do that..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

spring web flow tranisiton on-to

```
<view-state id="fileUpload" view="FileUpload" redirect="false" popup="false"    model="scanDataHolder">
    <on-render>
    <evaluate expression="fileUpload.setupNewFileUploadHolder(holder, flowRequestContext,externalContext)" />
    </on-render>
    <transition on="process" to="uploadreportTest" validate="false" />
    <transition on="doneWithFileUpload" to="doneWithFileUpload" validate="false"/>
    </view-state>
    <action-state id=" uploadreportTest">

      <evaluate expression="fileUpload.process(holder, flowRequestContext,externalContext)" />
    <transition on="success" to=" uploadreport " />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="uploadreport" view="renderReport"   redirect="false" popup="true" model="retailScan"/>
```